# How to make a spherical polyhedron (soccer or football ball) with three.js

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I'd like to make a `spherical polyhedron` (soccer or football ball) or something that approch it with `three.js`  but i did not find the way to make it.

My aim is to have something quite spherical with the same shape than a [truncated icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aUniform_tiling_532-t12.png) (faces with 5 and 6 edges)

Comment: Why not import a 3d model?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789627/understanding-the-geometry-of-a-truncated-icosahedron-for-rendering

Comment: it's not a duplicate because my question is about spherical polyhedron and not about truncated polyhedron

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the examples here: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shapes.html I believe it has the shape you are looking for. You essentially want to use the TetrahedronGeometry and change the subdivisions.

Comment: I tried different values with the IcosahedronGeometry but the global shape with differents parameters is not looking like a football ball. The tetrahedronGeometry is not the good shape for my purpose.